# jQuery Waypoint Plugin troubles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

I'm having slight troubles with the jQuery Waypoint plugin, and any information/help is appreciated.

Ok, so to define what I want to do:  I have images, that are hidden prior to being in the view area.  I want them to do an animation effect once in the view area.  That is the final result, for now, I'm still in testing as I am generally new to jQuery but getting better.

So I started out doing the shake on a single div, and it worked great once the once it was in view.  I used the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="shown">Shake it</div>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".shown").waypoint(function(direction) {
    $(this).effect("shake");
}, { offset: '95%', triggerOnce: true  });
});
```

Then I made two instances of the class='shown' in my HTML (one at top, and one at the bottom), and when I scrolled to them, they both worked great.  Plus, they both worked at separate times, which is what I'm trying to gain.

**Here's the trouble**

When I tried to 'display:none' and then animate to show on scroll, it animates BOTH, instead of just the single at a time.

This is what I'm using

HTML

```
<div class="shown" style="display: none;">
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".shown").waypoint(function(direction) {
    $(this).fadeIn( 10000, function() {
        // Animation complete
    });
}, { offset: '95%', triggerOnce: true  });
});
```

Ok, so just to clarify one more time :D (to be safe)

I want to be able to use the same class for MULTIPLE instances, that will only display once THAT element is in view.  Right now it's displaying ALL elements once 1 instance is in view.

Again, any information/help is appreciated.  You guys have a great community here, I'm glad I could join!

Comment: Solved answer on my own. Please close.

Comment: How's about sharing your answer so people with the same problem can learn?